# How to use Manipulate to cycle through a list of lists over a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

So I can do something like this which I like:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, {1,2,3,4}}]
```

It lets me pick which specific values I want to allow to be chosen for my function. But that list appears to be very limiting.

Lets say I have a list and each element contains a list of two elements like so:

```
myList = {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

How can I use `Manipulate` with this list such that it would give me two options to choose from: `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`

Here is what I have tried:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, myList}]
```

But it seems to only get it right on initialization and then when you touch the slider it goes haywire and starts choosing things like `1` and `3` intsead of `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`

I want to be able to use `Manipulate` but only have it work on a set pair of numbers.

Comment: maybe `Manipulate[i, {i, myList, SetterBar}]` or `Manipulate[i, {i, myList, RadioButtonBar}]`?

Comment: Or as you can find it in the documentation to `ControlType`: `Manipulate[i, {i, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you can obtain what you need by following way:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

Manipulate[list[[i]], {i, 1, Length@list, 1}]
```

This code always gives you the element (sublist) of initial list.

Comment: Just what I needed thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by ambiguity in the control-inferencing logic used by `Manipulate` and `Control` in the absence of an explicit control type specification.  A `Manipulate` value with a list of pairs is a valid specification for a `Slider`, `SetterBar`, `PopupMenu` or `InputField`.  `Manipulate` arbitrarily chooses to use a slider.

*Mathematica* uses various heuristics to determine what type of control to use.  These heuristics can be seen, for example, by inspecting the down-values of `` Manipulate`Dump`parameterToControls ``.  In version 10.0.2, the rules that are applicable when the control specification has the exhibited form are as follows (although I might have missed some rules in my quick scan):

- if the value is a list comprised of two-element sublists then use a `Slider`
- if the value is `{True,False}`, `{False,True}`, `{0,1}` or `{1,0}` then use a `Checkbox`
- if the value is a list has two to five values then use a `SetterBar`
- if the value is any other kind of list then use a `PopupMenu`
- if the value is a color then use a `ColorSlider`
- if the value is `Dynamic[...]` then use a `Manipulator`
- otherwise use an `InputField`

We can see that the first heuristic is being satisfied in our example, so a `Slider` is being used.  For a `Slider`, the specification `{{1,2},{3,4}}` indicates two values: the value `1` with relative width `2` and the value `3` with the relative width `4`.  Since there are only two values in the list, the relatives widths are unobservable in the slider behaviour.

We can also see that there are overlaps between the heuristic rules when it comes to lists.  The choice of control is somewhat arbitrary for the lists that fall into those overlaps.  If we are not satisfied with the heuristic choice, our only recourse is to explicitly specify the control type ourselves, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, SetterBar}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[i, {i, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

If we actually *want* to use a slider, then it is a bit trickier as we must work around the `{value, width}` notation in `Slider`:

```
Manipulate[i, {{i, {1, 2}}, Slider[Dynamic[i], {{{{1, 2}, 1}, {{3, 4}, 1}}}] &}]
```

Comment: I am deleting my answer in favor of your more complete and correct one.  Thanks for imparting knowledge. :-)